# calculate the mean over a set amount of ticks

Tags: set, mean, netlogo

I want the observer to calculate the mean of the number of floodings of a house (=patch) over the last 10 years (=ticks) when a certain action takes place (in this case, an insurance application by a turtle). This occurrence doesn't occur regularly, it can be regarded as a random occurrence (more or less).

So basically, I need some code that calculates the mean of floodings over the last 10 ticks when insurance application occurs.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is existing code? Do you have samples of what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `floodings` is a patch-variable and you'd like to determine the mean number of floodings for a given patch:

```
patches-own [
    floodings
    floodingsHistory
    floodingsMean10
]

; At the end of each tick, patches store the current 
; number of floodings in a list:

ask patches [ set floodingsHistory fput floodings floodingsHistory ]


; In case of [insurance application] patches (or a certain patch) calculate 
; the mean over a sublist that only comprises the values of the latest 10 ticks:

ask patches [ set floodingsMean10 mean (sublist floodingsHistory 0 10) ]
```

Comment: thanks, this partially helps me!
the question is actually a bit more complicated but I expected to be able to work around that. I can't take all patches into account, only those houses that had at least one flooding in the last 10 ticks. 
Thanks for your answer though, I'll ask my teacher tomorrow what I should use, I'll post that code here if possible to close the thread.

Comment: From the information given in your question this was as close as I could get, @user3484606. You could only let those patches calculate the mean that had at least one flooding during the last 10 ticks. It seems, however, easier to me to subset the patches once you actually want to do something with their means: For example `ask patches with [ floodingsMean10 >= 0.1 ] [ ... ]` or `show variance [ floodingsMean10 ] of patches with [ floodingsMean10 > 0.1 ]`.